# Ubuntu One: Constant "File Sync is disconnected" error

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, sync

I'm looking to upload a file to my Ubuntu One cloud, but when I open the Ubuntu One Control Panel on my Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal machine, it notifies me that "File Sync is disconnected." So, naturally, I'll click the "Connect" button next to it, and it will say "File Sync in progress..." and it will want to upload my file, but it doesn't seem like anything is happening. Then, after a minute, it will simply regress into "File Sync is disconnected." This, of course, frustrates me greatly, and causes me to wonder, is the Ubuntu One cloud server simply down? Or, if not, then what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: You can check to see if Ubuntu One is working properly by running "u1sdtool --status" in the terminal. If it's not working, see if "u1sdtool -q" and "u1sdtool --start" get it to syncing.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)